Permission denied (publickey). Error: Process completed with exit code 255. in github action workflow
name: Deploy to EC2
on:
push:
branches:
- main
jobs:
deploy:
runs-on: ubuntu-latest
steps:
- name: Checkout code
  uses: actions/checkout@v2

- name: Set up SSH agent
  uses: webfactory/ssh-agent@v0.5.3
  with:
    ssh-private-key: ${{ secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }}

- name: Deploy to EC2
  run: |
    ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ubuntu@54.234.235.218 "cd /home/ubuntu/my-app && git pull origin main && docker-compose down && docker-compose up -d --build"

i ran this yml file and try to deploy a basic mern app on ec2 using docker-compose file but getting this error  Permission denied (publickey). Error: Process completed with exit code 255
